# Show to select specific value from duplicated rows in SQL

Tags: sql, duplicates, azure-databricks

This is the simplification of the table I am working on right now.
Let's say I have this table with a duplicated record consisting of MADT, ID, DATE, and CODE named Table_a.

[image: Table]

From that table, I want to get a single record like the table below:

[image: Expected table]

At first, I tried this to get my desirable result

```
SELECT
    a.*
FROM
    Table_a a
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT b.*
                FROM Table_a b
                WHERE a.MANDT = b.MANDT 
                  AND a.ID = b.ID 
                  AND a.DATE > b.DATE)
```

But unfortunately, it's not the best code because I got a result like this.

[image: Result]

Is it possible to get the result I expected?

Could anyone help me?

I apologize if the question sounds basic because I'm still a newbie in SQL.

Comment: What if you have more then two records per `ID`? From which one you need the code and based on what logic?

Comment: @gotqn The actual data has more than three records per ID. I tried to filter the first date on the 'DATE' field to get the desirable 'CODE' value (not 999999). But in some IDs, the first date is associated with 999999.

Comment: Could you past your sample data (the first table screenshot) as text?

Comment: Please do not post data as images! Please edit your question to include the tables in text form ([markdown table](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables)). ID 124 has just two rows in your sample data and neither is a duplicate (based on `CODE`). What is the logic for returning `200` as opposed to `999999`? Similarly for ID 125, why `150` not `120`? Is it simple the most recent CODE that is not `999999`?

Answer (score 0):

Though in the case of duplicated records, we must have some criteria to distinguish two such records. For your expected result following Query would be sufficient:-

```
SELECT DISTINCT (ID), CODE FROM Table_a WHERE CODE < 1000
```

In the above code, since you want to select rows having Code 120, 150, 200. It seems you want to filter records by Code < 1000. Hence above query will return you the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Use the query `group by` the data by `ID` column and the minimum value of `Code` for each group of rows that have the same `ID` value. `WHERE` clause filters out any rows where the `Code` value is equal to `999999`.

```
%sql
SELECT  ID, MIN(Code) AS  Code
FROM <table_name>
WHERE  Code  <>  999999
GROUP  BY  ID
```

Comment: Please do not post images of code/data!